# WIldcard SSL Subdomain Not Pointing at Correct DocumentRoot 3

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, debian-wheezy, wildcard, documentroot

I have the same problem than:
[WIldcard SSL Subdomain Not Pointing at Correct DocumentRoot](https://serverfault.com/questions/440214/wildcard-ssl-subdomain-not-pointing-at-correct-documentroot)
but the answer does not help me.

I have a Wildcard SSL installed on my Apache server.

With HTTP :

- www.example.com points to documentroot /home/example/public_html OK
- sub.example.com points to documentroot /home/sub_example/public_html OK

Now with HTTPS:

- www.example.com points to documentroot /home/example/public_html OK
- sub.example.com points to documentroot /home/example/public_html (NOK: same as main domain above).

I have checked the .conf files into /etc/apache2/sites-available and they are OK, at least for the documentroot directive.

Why subdomain points to the main domain documentroot? and this only when SSL?

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a virtual host configuration issue.  Have a look at the output of `apache2 -S`.

On Ubuntu I had to source some environment variables first and ran:  `( . /etc/apache2/envvars ; apache2 -S )`

Comment: Thanks to the command "apache2ctl -S", I saw there was an IP misconfiguration: subdomain had not the same IP than main domain. Now this is corrected.

Comment: But now, when I go to subdomain, the browser says this is a selfsigned certificate. Subdomain does not take the maindomain certificate, although this is a wildcard certificate.

Comment: I had to recopy the certificate files in the subdomain directory. Now everything just work fine. And I have the green padlock. This apache2ctl -S command really helped me. :)